# How do I identify whether a person is enrolled throughout specific dates in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| MemberID | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+----------+------------+------------+
|    10    | 2015-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
|    10    | 2015-06-15 | 9999-12-31 |
|    20    | 2015-01-01 | 2015-04-06 |
|    20    | 2015-04-07 | 9999-12-31 |
|    30    | 2015-05-06 | 9999-12-31 |
|    40    | 2015-01-01 | 2015-03-01 |
|    50    | 2015-01-01 | 2015-08-31 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

Based on this table, I want to find the MemberIds who are CONTINUOUSLY eligible from 1 Jan 2015 - 31 Aug 2015.

**Business Rules:**

- Even if the member has a gap of one day in his membership, he is disqualified.
- Same member ID may have different entries in table (Example MemberID 10)
- In the demo table, Member 10, 20, 50 should be included in the result table as they are eligible throughout the entire period

Comment: Have you attempted anything or are you just dumping this on SO?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried the following  SELECT distinct *
FROM table
WHERE (StartDate <  '2015-01-02' and EndDate > '2015-08-30'). Now I don;t understand how i accommodate the IDs which are like customer 20 in the above table

Comment: The sum of the differences between start and end date for a given ID over a single year must add up to 365.  For #20 this is not the case.  I expect the answer to your question to be a query of medium to high difficulty, but this is what Gordon Linoff is for.

Comment: Can we assume you are only dealing with 2015 right now?

Comment: Yes. Only 2015 data through september. But there are many entries for  single MemberID. Example, a member may have a start date of 1- jan to 30jan. the same member may also have one entry from 1 jan to 30 june and 1 jan to 30 may and 1 jan to 30 jul. In such a case the date diff may be greater than the number of days, but te member is still not eligible

Comment: What datatype is `StartDate` and `EndDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach here is:

**1.** Locate continuous dates for a member, i.e. if EndDate is `2015-04-06` AND `StartDate` of next row is `2015-04-07`, merge them to single row. This is achieved by the following statement:

```
SELECT 
        MemberID, MIN(StartDate) StartDate, MAX(EndDate) EndDate
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        dt.*,
            IF(@previd = dt.memberid
                && DATE_ADD(@prevdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= dt.StartDate, @groupid, @groupid:=@groupid + 1) GroupId,
            @previd:=dt.memberid,
            @prevdate:=dt.EndDate
    FROM
        data_table dt, (SELECT @previd:=NULL, @prevdate:=NULL, @groupid:=0) a
    ORDER BY MemberID , StartDate) memberdategrouptable
    GROUP BY GroupId
```

You may consider as iterating over the results ordered by `MemberID`,`StartDate` and `if(found_different_member || (member_same_as_previous_row && previous_end_date_does_not_match_to_current_start_date) assign_new_group_id`.

This will fetch the following results:

### First Result

```
    +----------+------------+------------+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+
    | MemberID | StartDate  | EndDate    | GroupId | @previd:=dt.memberid | @prevdate:=dt.EndDate |
    +----------+------------+------------+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+
    |       10 | 2015-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |       1 |                   10 | 9999-12-31            |
    |       10 | 2015-06-15 | 9999-12-31 |       2 |                   10 | 9999-12-31            |
    |       20 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-04-06 |       3 |                   20 | 2015-04-06            |
    |       20 | 2015-04-07 | 9999-12-31 |       3 |                   20 | 9999-12-31            |
    |       30 | 2015-05-06 | 9999-12-31 |       4 |                   30 | 9999-12-31            |
    |       40 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-03-01 |       5 |                   40 | 2015-03-01            |
    |       50 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-08-31 |       6 |                   50 | 2015-08-31            |
    +----------+------------+------------+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+
```

### Group to continuous date

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| MemberID | StartDate  | EndDate    |
+----------+------------+------------+
|       10 | 2015-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
|       10 | 2015-06-15 | 9999-12-31 |
|       20 | 2015-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
|       30 | 2015-05-06 | 9999-12-31 |
|       40 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-03-01 |
|       50 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-08-31 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

**2.** List items matching date criteria

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        MemberID, MIN(StartDate) StartDate, MAX(EndDate) EndDate
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        dt.*,
            IF(@previd = dt.memberid
                && DATE_ADD(@prevdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= dt.StartDate, @groupid, @groupid:=@groupid + 1) GroupId,
            @previd:=dt.memberid,
            @prevdate:=dt.EndDate
    FROM
        data_table dt, (SELECT @previd:=NULL, @prevdate:=NULL, @groupid:=0) a
    ORDER BY MemberID , StartDate) memberdategrouptable
    GROUP BY GroupId) memberdaterange 
WHERE
    StartDate <= '2015-01-01'
        AND EndDate >= '2015-08-31'
```

### Reuslt

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| MemberID | StartDate  | EndDate    |
+----------+------------+------------+
|       10 | 2015-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
|       20 | 2015-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
|       50 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-08-31 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, which is rather painful in MySQL.  The idea is to assign a group id to each row.  The group id is the cumulative sum of a period starting.  And, a period starts when there is no previous record.

So, the following should assign the group, assuming that the `StartDate` is always one day after the previous `EndDate` (this condition can be relaxed but it somewhat simplifies the coding):

```
select t.*,
       (@grp := if(@m = MemberId and @e = date_sub(StartDate, interval 1 day), @grp,
                   if(@m := MemberId, if(@e := EndDate, @grp + 1, @grp + 1), @grp + 1
                     )
                   )
       ) as grp
from (select t.*,
             (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.MemberId = t.MemberId and
                    t2.EndDate = date_sub(t.StartDate, interval 1 day)
             ) as IsPeriodStart
      from table t
     ) t cross join
     (select @m := 0, @e := 0, @grp := 0) params
order by MemberId, StartDate;
```

Then, the answer to your question is simply an aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select MemberId
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(@m = MemberId and @e = date_sub(StartDate, interval 1 day), @grp,
                         if(@m := MemberId, if(@e := EndDate, @grp + 1, @grp + 1), @grp + 1
                           )
                         )
             ) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (select 1
                    from table t2
                    where t2.MemberId = t.MemberId and
                          t2.EndDate = date_sub(t.StartDate, interval 1 day)
                   ) as IsPeriodStart
            from table t
           ) t cross join
           (select @m := 0, @e := 0, @grp := 0) params
      order by MemberId, StartDate
     ) t
group by MemberId, grp
having min(StartDate) <= '2015-01-01' and max(EndDate) >- '2015-08-31';
```

EDIT:

I realize that this can be simplified considerably.  You don't need the variables.  Someone is continuous during the period if the `IsPeriodStart` flag is never true during that time:

```
select MemberId
from (select t.*,
             (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.MemberId = t.MemberId and
                    t2.EndDate = date_sub(t.StartDate, interval 1 day)
             ) as IsPeriodStart
      from table t
      where EndDate >= '2015-01-01' and StartDate <= '2015-08-31'
     ) t 
group by MemberId
having max(case when IsPeriodStart then StartDate end) = min(StartDate) and
       min(StartDate) <= '2015-01-01' and
       max(EndDate) >= '2015-08-31';
```

The three conditions in the `having` clause do the work.  The last two should be  obvious -- the period is covered.  The first is saying that the only period start in the range is the first record; hence, there are no gaps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is if you have a Member Table, add a `Eligible` flag column.

1. First set all of them (Eligible) to true
2. Then set selected ones to false with something like this

.

```
 update Member set Eligible = false
 where Member.MemberId =  
   (select A.MemberId from tbl A
    left outer join tbl B on A.MemberId = B.MemberId
    where A.EndDate <> '9999-12-31'
    and A.EndDate +1 < B.StartDate)
```

Note its not strict mysql as I dont know the data types of your fields.